# What is the best way to make a pip package with optional functionality?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, extra

I have my own pip package, which is called `my_package`.
It's quite large, and I want to split it into a few packages, which I can optionally install if necessary.
So my goal is: to have main package called `my_package`, and some extra packages (for example, `my_package[extra1]`), which can extend functionality of the main package.

I've done some research, and found out that you can specify `[project.optional-dependencies]` in pyproject.toml file, and it will install neccessary optional dependencies to your project.
And it seems like a good idea: to make an optional functionality as a separate pip package.

But the question is: how to gracefully implement it into the main package?
I mean, I want to install this "extra" package by `pip install my_package[extra1]`, and it should lead to automatically added functionality to my project.

Under the hood it just installes a different package, but how to use it by the main package?

Should I check the dependency existance in environment by some way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+namespace+packages

Comment: Thank you!
I've figured out.